what i causing my registration page not to go to the login page, yet the button onclick is well provided in the java code
I have the validate User and write account to firebase methods aswell.
I adjusted the read and write settings in my firebase database, I also disabled SignIn methods that rely on "cross-origin redirects and still the problem persisted. on the mobile phone, when you click the Register button, you see an error authentification failed yet actually the account is seen the the users authentification in firebase. Am really fade up!
  <pre><code>  `package com.example.libmgt;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class activity_registration extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText emailInput, memberId, password, telephone, age;
    private Button registerButton;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    public static class User {
        public String email, memberId, telephone, password;
        public int age;

        public User() {
            // Required empty constructor
        }

        public User(String email, String memberId, String password, String telephone, int age) {
            this.email = email;
            this.memberId = memberId;
            this.telephone = telephone;
            this.age = age;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

        emailInput = findViewById(R.id.emailInput);
        registerButton = findViewById(R.id.register_button);
        memberId = findViewById(R.id.member_id);
        password = findViewById(R.id.passwordInput);
        telephone = findViewById(R.id.telephone);
        age = findViewById(R.id.age);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        registerButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String email = emailInput.getText().toString().trim();
            String memberIdValue = memberId.getText().toString().trim();
            String passwordValue = password.getText().toString().trim();
            String telephoneValue = telephone.getText().toString().trim();
            String ageValue = age.getText().toString().trim();

            if (validateUserInput(email, memberIdValue, passwordValue, telephoneValue, ageValue)) {
                writeAccountDataToFirebase(email, memberIdValue, passwordValue, telephoneValue, Integer.parseInt(ageValue));
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean validateUserInput(String email, String memberId, String password, String telephone, String age) {
        if (email.isEmpty() || !Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            emailInput.setError("Invalid email");
            return false;
        }
        else if (password == null || password.length() < 6) {
            this.password.setError("Invalid password");
                      return false;
        }
        else if (age.isEmpty() || !age.matches("\\d+")) {
            this.age.setError("Invalid age");
            return false;
        }
        else if (Integer.parseInt(age) < 18) {
            this.age.setError("Age must be at least 18");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            writeAccountDataToFirebase(email, memberId, password, telephone, Integer.parseInt(age));
            return true;

        }
    }

    private void writeAccountDataToFirebase(String email, String memberId, String password, String telephone, int age) {
        Log.d("Registration", "writeAccountDataToFirebase() called");
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d("Registration", "createUserWithEmail:success");
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                DatabaseReference userRef = database.getReference("users");
                User userData = new User(email, password, memberId, telephone, age);
                assert user != null;
                userRef.child(user.getUid()).setValue(userData, (error, ref) -> {
                    if (error == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity_registration.this, "Account created successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                            startActivity(new Intent(activity_registration.this, activity_login.class));
                            finish();
                        }, 1000);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(activity_registration.this, "Registration failed: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Log.w("Registration", "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(activity_registration.this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}

`


I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

that is the code snippet for the registration page that is displayin an error popup on the launched mobile app "Authentification Failed" yet the registration is filled without violating any of the set authentification rules in my code. I realised the in my firebase Authentification, regardless of the error the account is written there but now i have no way to move to the login page. hope you understand my frustration
